# Neo4j PostingsFormat with name 'BlockTreeOrds' does not exist

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I tried to packaged my project. But when I run the jar file, I find a bug.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, D:\f
    ...
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine@5483163c' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat with name 'BlockTreeOrds' does not exist.  You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.  The current classpath supports the following names: [Lucene50]
```

...

I use maven to package the project.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>db.PostgreSQL</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The project is work when I directly run it in Intellij.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution. Using the follow maven plugin to package the project.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>

                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```